# Does a private folder always stay as such on GitHub?

Tags: user-accounts, privacy, github

I am asking because I have a free account on GitHub as a student which it seems will expire over time and now I have a few private repositories.

Will they become public?

Comment: This would probably be a better question to ask of Github's customer support.

Comment: [Click here and read an answer posted by a GitHub employee.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361700/what-happens-to-a-github-student-accounts-repositories-at-the-end-of-2-years)